# .NET MAUI expand animation

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I’d like to create a typical expand animation. From 0 to 100% of the height but without using explicit HeightRequest. I tried to set IsVisible to false and ScaleY to 0 and then set IsVisible to true and animate ScaleY. The problem is that as soon as I set it to true the whole place is reserved immeriately.
And if I want to rely on automatic height then I don’t know it upfront.

Question: how to do it? A concept without code is sufficient.

**UPDATE** My code

```xml
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Frame Margin="10">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Button Text="Expand" Clicked="Expand"/>
                <Label
                    x:Name="Expandable"
                    Text="Hidden Text"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    IsVisible="False"
                    ScaleY="0"
                    AnchorY="0"
                />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

```cs
    void Expand(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Expandable.IsVisible = true;
        Expandable.ScaleYTo(scale: 1.0, length: 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code so far!!

Comment: @FreakyAli Here you go. I hope it will help

Comment: If you comment out `Expandable.ScaleYTo(..` line, what happens? If you change that line to `..(scale: 0.5, ..`, what happens?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The same. I mean After setting `IsVisible` to `true` the full space is reserved for the label. In both cases. In the first case it's just an empty space. In the second case the label takes half.

Comment: Ok. So ScaleYTo 0.5 does affect the size. That is a start. I wonder if there is a bug when ScaleY starts at 0. Or when it starts invisible. In XAML, `ScaleY="1" IsVisible="True"`. In c#, `scale: 0.5`. Does it animate?

Comment: I am having the same challenge here, have you figured it out?

Comment: @Karro I ended up with defining all dimensions explicitly (like `HeightRequest="100") so that I know the final size so that I can start an animation setting a size to 0 and then visibility to True and only then run an animation. But of course it doesn't work if you are not able to define a size (like multiline text).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Frame Margin="10">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Button Text="Expand" Clicked="Expand"/>
            <Label
                x:Name="Expandable"
                Text="Hidden Text"
                FontSize="Large"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                IsVisible="False"
            />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Frame>
</VerticalStackLayout>


private double _expandedHeight;
private uint _animationDuration;

public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _expandedHeight = 150; // Set a value that suits you
    _animationDuration = 1000;
}
```

Then you can animate height of youy control to a requested size.

```
void Expand(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Expandable.IsVisible = true;
    Expandable.Animate("Expand", length: _animationDuration, animation: new Animation(x => Expandable.HeightRequest = x, 0, _expandedHeight, easing: Easing.SinOut));
}
```

I'm not sure how to find a desired size for the control upfront. Maybe someone can help with this?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**